# How to hide web not available page in android when button clicked?

Tags: android

How to hide web not available page in android when button clicked on link ? please any can send code for it.

**my code**

```
package com.example.mysd;    
import android.content.Intent;    
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;    
import android.widget.Button;



public class mysd extends Activity {

 Button button1;

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mysd);

    addListenerOnButton1();

}


public void addListenerOnButton1() {


    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);


    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View arg0) {

          Intent browserIntent = 

                        new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Uri.parse("http://www.google.com/"));

            startActivity(browserIntent);

        }

    });

 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code,

```
WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
progressBar = new ProgressDialog(Activity.this, "Loading...");

web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        progressBar.show();
    }

    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        if (progressBar.isShowing()) {
            progressBar.dismiss();
        }
    }

    public void onReceivedError(WebView webView, int errorCode,
                                String description, String failingUrl) {

        super.onReceivedError(webView, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
        try {
            webView.stopLoading();
        } catch (Exception e) {//
        }
        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        }
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity.this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Error Message");
        alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE,
                "Try Again", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                        startActivity(getIntent());
                    }
                });
        alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                    }
                });
        if (progressBar.isShowing()) {
            progressBar.dismiss();
        }
        alertDialog.show();
    }
});
web.loadUrl("http://your_url");
```

Please note that, few functions in the above code is deprecated. Instead of Intent use a webview in you app. (Add webview in the layout file of the activity)